# "I have a conversation about chemistry"

Tags: modifiers

> I had a conversation **about chemistry**.

It literally means I talked about chemistry with somebody.

Does it make the same sense if "about chemistry" modifies verb "had a converstion", not noun "a conversation"?

I think it's adverbial because "about chemistry" can be moved in front of the clause, "about chemistry, I had a conversation", and I can put a comma betweem, "I had a conversation, about chemistry".

Comment: What makes you think that it can?

Comment: @KateBunting Because "I take a walk home" is possible like "I walk home".

Comment: That's irrelevant. _Take a walk_ is a phrase replacing the verb _walk_ - it doesn't change the order of phrases in the sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting Take a look at, have a look at, take a walk to, take a stroll to, take a trip to.

Comment: About chemistry, I had a conversation. is not grammatical in English in normal parlance. "about chemistry" is a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I had* [*a conversation about chemistry*].

"A conversation about chemistry" is a constituent, a noun phrase, in which the preposition phrase "about chemistry" modifies "conversation".

Compare the pseudo-cleft equivalent:

> [*A conversation about chemistry*] *was what I had*.

Comment: Then, is it wrong that "about chemistry" modifies "had a conversation"?

Comment: @Faints Yes. As I said, the PP "about chemistry" modifies "conversation".

Answer (score 1):

> I had a conversation **about chemistry**.

*about chemistry* can't modify *had*.  The phrase also can't be moved as it is adjectival here.

To make the phrase modify a verb, we could restructure the sentence:

> I **conversed about chemistry** with somebody.

As the phrase is adverbial,  it can be moved:

> I **conversed** with somebody **about chemistry**.

**conversed** allows preposition phrases to be inserted after it as it is intransitive, unlike **had**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me a moot point, and somewhat irrelevant, as to whether the conversation was "about chemistry", or whether the having of that conversation was about chemistry. Hence the question of whether the phrase "about chemistry" is adjectival or adverbial is also moot - and to my mind equally irrelevant.

Moving "about chemistry" to the front of the sentence, although grammatically correct, would make it an altogether quaint and unusual expression - unless it were being done as part of poetic licence. "About chemistry, I had a conversation" in normal speech would only work if you really wanted to place great emphasis on chemistry eg. "I refute utterly that I had any conversation with him about geography - but about chemistry, yes I did have a convesation".

**But I am not sure that this clears up the question as to whether the "about chemistry" is modifying "convesation" or the verb "have".**

Comment: Fronting the prepositional phrase *about chemistry* sounds like the speech of the stereotypical Jewish grandmother scolding, “Veet soch a men you hodd to get eenvolved?”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Chemistry? You had a conversation about. [haha]. Maybe the grandmother would miss the "about"?