# "To take a walk to home"

Tags: modifiers

> "I took a walk to home".

I think "to home" modifies noun "walk", not verb "took". Is it right?

I think "took" itself isn't connected to direction, but "walk" is.

> "I took a trip to France".

Likewise, does "to France" modify "a trip"?

Comment: We would usually say 'I walked home'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Hi, Michael, could you tell me whether in "I took a walk/step/stroll/trip to somewhere" "to somewhere" modifies nouns?

Comment: First, drop the "to" -- it's not needed. "Home" is a preposition, here meaning "to my normal place of residence". "Home" then modifies "walk". The PP "to France modifies "trip".

Comment: @BillJ James thinks "to France" modifies verb "take a trip". I don't know which is true!

Comment: @Faints That would be preferable, in which case the PP "to France" is an adjunct (modifier) in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ Could you answer https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346309/i-have-a-conversation-about-chemistry ?

Comment: On reflection, I'd say that "home" is modifying the nominal "walk". Compare the pseudo-cleft "[A walk home] was what I took". And "to France" modifies "trip". Compare "[A trip to France] was what I took."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct here.

The verb "take" has a number of meanings. "I took the medicine" can mean I swallowed it, or it can mean I carried it away from where it was. "I took the medicine home" means I carried it from where it was to my home. "I took a walk home" means I walked to my home. The sentence is more like "I took the medicine", and the thing I took was "a walk home".

Incidentally, we usually leave out "to" when the destination is home. We put it in for other destinations, e.g. "to the shops", and we put it in if we are specifying "to my home". I'm not sure if there is any particular reason why, or if it just one of those things about English.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: There is reason: "home" is a preposition with the meaning "at/from/in/to one's normal place of residence. In the OP's example, the last of those preps applies.

Comment: @BillJ, yes, like *away*, *there*, *back*, *out* etc. But "away" is not synonymous with "to my away".

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking the wrong question.  I'm going to use "I took a trip to France" for my answer, as "I took a trip to home" is non-idiomatic.

There are at least two reasonable structural analyses of this.  Firstly "a trip to France" is a valid noun phrase. So it could be a constituent of the sentence.  But also "took a trip" is a valid verb phrase, and so "to France" could be a adjunct to that verb phrase. There is more than one valid way to parse.

Now sometimes this matters:

> I saw a man with a telescope.

There are two ways to understand this.  1)  There was a man holding a telescope, and I saw this man. 2) I was using a telescope and I saw the man. Without context it is ambiguous, but even a little context helps enormously. "I saw a man looking at stars with a telescope" / "I saw a man with my telescope." We know how to parse the sentence because we understand the meaning.  I don't know how one's brain does this. It works out the meaning from the syntax, but it can't work out the syntax until it knows the meaning!  Nobody really knows how brains do language.

But in your sentence, both structures result in the same understanding:
"I took a trip" and "It was a trip to France".

So when you ask 'does "to France" modify "a trip"' You are asking which parse tree is correct.  But the only way to determine that would be if the two parse trees had different meanings, and if we could pragmatically reject one of the meanings.  Since the two parse trees have the same meaning, there is no way to determine which is "correct".

Finally,  "a trip" normally suggests a journey away from home, and idiomatically "home" often doesn't require "to".  So you don't say "I took a trip to home".  Instead you might say "I went home".

In the future, you can think "Is there a difference meaning between the different parse trees."  If there is a difference then from context, which is more likely.  If there is no difference in meaning then the syntactic ambiguity can be ignored.  If there is a difference in meaning, but one meaning is more likely then you can reject the other parse tree.  If there is a difference in meaning, and the two meanings are equally likely, there is syntactic ambiguity.

Finally an old Groucho Marx joke which you can practice this on:

> I went on safari, and I shot an elephant in my pyjamas! ... How he got in my pyjamas I'll never know.

Comment: I can't imagine "to France" modifies "take a trip"... "Take" has no direction.

Comment: Look at the verb phrase, not just the verb.  Does "take a trip" have a direction?

Comment: But as I said,  wrong question.  Having read "Joe took a trip to France"  can you answer these two questions  "What did Joe do?"  and "Where did Joe go?"  If you can answer both, then you have achieved 100% understanding.  You don't need to know what modifies and what is modified.

Comment: Then do you think in "I had a conversation about him" "about him" modifies "had a conversation"?

Comment: Wrong question!

Comment: Please... That was a main problem.

Comment: No.  Wrong question.  There are several valid parse trees of the surface syntax.  The only way to determine which parse tree is correct is by understanding the meaning.  But if all parse trees result in the same meaning, then 1) you can't decide which is correct and 2) it doesn't matter!  In other words,  not "the main problem" because "not a problem at all!"

Comment: Then if "about him" modifies "had a conversation"  does it mean the same when "about him" modifies "conversation"?

Comment: See your other question.

Comment: OP has also posted an actual question about the parsing of [I had a conversation about chemistry.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346309/) Is that not the same basic issue? Parsing #1: *{about} **chemistry*** adverbially modifies ***had a conversation***, as in *I **discussed / talked about** chemistry*. Parsing #2: *{about} **chemistry*** adjectivally modifies ***a conversation***, same as *a **serious** conversation*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does it make sense if "about chemistry" modifies "had a conversation"?